# zsh: command not found: swag

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-gin, gin-swagger

I'm struggling with `gin-swagger` to set OpenAPI documentation on several APIs written in `gin`. While I installed the package in the project route via `go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@latest` I am not able to run the `swag init`!

```
swag init
```

Out:

```
zsh: command not found: swag
```

---

Here's the repo [link](https://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized the problem was related to the `GOPATH`!

I went through the `~/go/bin` path and saw the `swag` there indicating it is installed properly. Then, I opened the `.zshrc` file to check the variables which were as follows:

```bash
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
GOPATH=~/.go
PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Next, I rectified the `GOPATH` from `GOPATH=~/.go` to `GOPATH=~/go` to solve the issue.

Now, `swag init` works.

Comment: You should not set GOROOT in your environment.

Comment: @JimB Can you elaborate more on it? or introdume me a link to read more about go installation and its environment?

Comment: It's kind of elaborated by omission, nothing in the official docs (like [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code)) ever mentions setting `GOROOT`, because even mentioning its existance seemed to make people think they must use it all the time for some reason. You only need to set `GOROOT` to override the discovered location of the toolchain, which is usually only needed in some special cases when developing that toolchain, and otherwise will cause confusing errors when you don't expect it.